# Is ice on ERV door normal?

Tags: hvac, erv

My ERV is forming ice and condensation on the top of the door and on top of the unit (presumably because the fresh air intake is on that side).  The outside tempersture hit about 1 degree F today.    Is this normal?

I previously had issues with condensation and ice forming in the flex duct intake but after the installers replaced it with R8 insulated flex duct it seems to be ok thus far.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not normal at all for the new ERV's (last 15-years). The defrost sensor that's supposed to close the intake damper isn't working. It won't cause air problems for anyone, but it will rust the unit & possibly allow mold to take up residence in the unit's area & you don't want either.